# JQuery / Laravel - Enable Input Texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, forms

I want to enable all input texts here how can I do it with the scripts? please 
provide me with a script and 
help me as im new to in jquery thank you very much!!!

My ***INPUT TEXTS***

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
        {{Form::label('air_code', 'Airline Code')}}<br>
        {{Form::text('air_code', $setting->air_code, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Flight Number','disabled'])}}
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
        {{Form::label('Flight_No', 'Flight No.')}}<br>
        {{Form::text('Flight_No', $setting->Flight_No, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Flight Number','disabled'])}}
        </div>
```

my ***BUTTON***

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name='edit' value='Edit'>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will do the your work.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-success', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $("input").prop('disabled', false);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
     $("input").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
     });
   })
});
```

**NB:** Don't forget to import jquery.js before you call this script

**Hope this will help you**

Answer (score -1):

```
            $(document).on('click', '.btn-success', function(e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $("input").prop('disabled', false);
                  // you can use class or id of input field
                 // or you can use it like
                 $("input").attr('disabled', false);
                 // disabled false make it enable
                })
```

Comment: (1) first specfiy when do you want to remove, means at what action?

Comment: If you want to remove from all input then first define class on all input box and put class name instead of input in selector . Example  $(".class_name").attr('disabled', false)

Comment: $("input").attr('disabled', false); will false atttibite of first input box only not for all dude